# How to make Page in UWP generic

Tags: c#, generics, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

after a little research I found out that we can't use generic types in Page, like this:

```
public class MyPage<T> : Page where T : class
```

The reason of this is that we can't tell to the xaml file of the page what is this T(correct me if I am wrong).
I saw one possible solution on the internet where it was happening something like this:

```
//this page has only cs file 
public class MyPage<T> : Page where T : class
{
}


//this page again is constructed only from cs file
public class BasePage : MyPage<ViewModel>
{
}

//at last we have a page with xaml file that can be shown
public class MainPage : BasePage
{
}
```

As you see this code looks vary strange and I really don't like this solution.

So can someone purpose a good solution to this problem? Maybe with an example.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Do you have an example?

Comment: At a minimum you would need to make the class `internal` since WinRT doesn't support open genetics. Does `typeof(Page<Foo>)` not work?

Comment: The goal is when a new Page is created, the Page will have some basic implementation that can be used from the BasePage and will be bound with the ViewModel that will be passed as a generic type, e.g. if I have method in the BasePage 
`public abstract void DoSomething(T viewModel);` 
when I use this method in the Page, I will do this 
`public void DoSomething(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
//some cool stuff
}` and I will get the type of object that I am expecting without the need of a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, as this is not supported in the current XAML spec. Creating a Page is a great idea, by the way, especially for strongly-typing a view-model property. The platform team knows about this request, by the way. You can, however, implement `IView<T>` if you want a work around.